# Automatically deduce lambda arguments from member function signature

Tags: c++, c++11

Usually, I use lambda functions to set callbacks to member functions for 3rd party libraries. For example:

```cpp
setCallback([this](auto&& ...x) { handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...); });
```

Now I have a library with an overloaded function to set the callback, making this line ambiguous:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Library
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (int)> IntFunction;
    typedef std::function<void (int, int)> IntIntFunction;

    void setCallback(IntFunction f) { f_int_ = f; }
    void setCallback(IntIntFunction f) { f_int_int_ = f; }

    void callCallback(int a, int b) {
        if (f_int_) f_int_(a);
        if (f_int_int_) f_int_int_(a, b);
    }

private:
    IntFunction f_int_;
    IntIntFunction f_int_int_;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {
        //lib.setCallback([this](auto&& ...x) { handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...); });
        lib.setCallback([this](int a, int b) { handleCallback(a, b); });
    }

    void handleCallback(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "handleCallback: " << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
    }

    Library lib;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myclass;
    myclass.lib.callCallback(2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to automatically deduce the right arguments from the `handleCallback` function to avoid having a duplicate of the function arguments in the lambda?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There's only one shown `handleCallback` function, so there's nothing to deduce here.

Comment: It's about the `setCallback` function. In the line I commented out, the compiler cannot deduce the `auto`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with overloading. That is simply not valid C++. This is not how variadic parameter packs work. Basically, any time you have `...something` (or `something...`, or some variation of that), there has to be, in so many words, "template<typename ...something>" somewhere nearby. Where is it, here?

Comment: If you remove one of the `setCallback` functions, it works: [see here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zDLjVHbmlpIgbQZb).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The generic lambda introduces the parameter pack in its parameter list. And I don't see any `...` outside that lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create function for that:

```
class MyClass
{
    template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
    void setCallback(Ret (MyClass::*member)(Args...) /*const*/) {
        lib.setCallback([=](Args...args)
            {
                (this->*member)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            });
    }

public:
    MyClass() { setCallback(&MyClass::handleCallback); }

    void handleCallback(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "handleCallback: " << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
    }

    Library lib;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94a6e8321f5f2d57)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to properly lift the function, especially the return type expression since it will enable SFINAE, making it possible for the `std::function` constructor to detect if the lambda is able to be called:

```
lib.setCallback([this](auto&& ...x) -> 
    decltype(void(handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...))) {
        handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);
    }
);
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/UFyEkd)

You can also forward noexceptness:

```
lib.setCallback([this](auto&& ...x)
    noexcept(noexcept(handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...)))
    -> decltype(void(handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...))) {
        handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);
    }
);
```

At that point, the only sane way to do it is to use a macro:

```
#define RETURNS(...) noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
    -> decltype((__VA_ARGS__)) {                         \
        return __VA_ARGS__;                              \
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
lib.setCallback([this](auto&& ...x) RETURNS(handleCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...)));
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/WDYLlO)

Comment: I really like this approach, because it avoids defining a new function while the intention is still clear. However, I accepted Jarod42's answer, because here's still one duplicate of `handleCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

From the given answers I constructed this function:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename TClass, typename TRet, typename ...Args>
auto getLambda(TClass *instance, TRet (TClass::*member)(Args...))
{
    if constexpr (std::is_void<TRet>::value)
        return [=](Args...args){ (instance->*member)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
    else
        return [=](Args...args){ return (instance->*member)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
}
```

It can be used in this way:

```cpp
lib.setCallback(getLambda(this, &MyClass::handleCallback));
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I7odffwVUnKTdIfH)

Now I'm using it to replace the lambda functions I used before (as shown in the question) since it improves readability.